# How to loop and count sum of cells with condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a cell that is using the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TRIM($A10:$A2003)<>"")*1)
```

This formula is counting the far left column below if the cell is not blank. This is functioning fine. Its output is outlined in red.

What I am trying to accomplish now is setting up a condition/formula that will do the same thing, sumproduct if the cell is not blank, however for rows where the "Division" column equal specific things.

I was going to do this:

```
=IF($F12="CAC", SUMPRODUCT((TRIM($A10:$A2003)<>"")*1),"")
```

However, won't this only check $F12? I need this to check every row down. Check if F12 is true and then check if A12 is not blank. If both true, it counts 1 and then continues to go down the list.

How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Working formula -

[image]

Non-working formula
[image]

Error Message:

[image]

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((TRIM($A10:$A2003)<>"")*($F10:$F2003="CAC"))`

Comment: @ScottCraner How would this check if the division is a certain value though?

Comment: Never mind, I see you just edited.  Sorry for the additional newb question, but if I wanted to check if it equals either CAC, CLE or CLW, would I just do `="CAC", "CLE", "CLW"`?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((TRIM($A10:$A2003)<>"")*(ISNUMBER(MATCH($F10:$F2003,{"CAC", "CLE", "CLW"},0))))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you. I am running into an issue though. If I copy the formula from D3 and paste it anywhere else (even with doing ctrl+shift+enter) if zeros out. I think that is messing up this equation. The same thing happens if I isolate the first part of your equation, `=SUMPRODUCT((TRIM($A10:$A2003)<>"")`. I get a zero.

Comment: copy the formula and not the cell.  If you copy the cell the references will change, unless you make the whole reference absolute: `=SUMPRODUCT((TRIM($A$10:$A$2003)<>"")*(ISNUMBER(MATCH($F$10:$F$2003,{"CAC", "CLE", "CLW"},0))))`

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried copying only the formula. It still keeps zeroing out.

Comment: What is the formula in the cell in which you copy.  Also check the data to make sure there are no other characters, seen or not seen in the F column.  It is looking for an exact match.

Comment: @ScottCraner See the edits in the question above. I posted two screenshots for what I am seeing. The copying of the formula is not rendering the same result.

Comment: @ScottCraner There is now a prompt showing up. It says: `Microsoft Excel cannot calculate a formula. There is a circular reference in an open workbook, but the references that cause it cannot be listed for you. Try editing the last formula you entered or removing it with the Undo command.` This was after I entered the formula you posted.